# Android, Fragments, Google Map: Error IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id --- for fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Need some help guys.

I'm working a small Android app, that gets JSON data from a URI, and adds any active Cyclones it finds into a list and displays it. All that is working fine.

I decided to place a Fragment in the app to display Google maps. I've not worked with Fragments much at all, and this is where the trouble starts.

This is the onCreate From MainActivity.java

**CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<CycloneData>>
```

I'll cut out most of the code that does not apply.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cyclone_list);

...
    //cutting code above, out to simplify
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    CycloneMap mapFrag = new CycloneMap();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.google_map, mapFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.google_map, mapFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This is from my Fragment class "CycloneMap.java". I think the problem is in the onCreateView Inflater....but I cannot figure out what/why. I am also probably very wrong about this.

**CODE**

```
public class CycloneMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

//Defining Google Map objects variables
GoogleMap mMap;
boolean mapReady=false;

static final CameraPosition START_POINT = CameraPosition.builder()
        .target(new LatLng(38.1254, -101.1703))
        .zoom(3)
        .bearing(340)
        .tilt(15)
        .build();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}

@Override
//onMapReady CallBack method
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    //Setting mapReady to true
    mapReady=true;

    //Loading local instance map from Callback
    mMap = map;

    //Set camera at starting point, high over the middle of the U.S of A.
    initialCameraPosition(START_POINT);
}

private void initialCameraPosition(CameraPosition target) {
    //Setting position to the target created above
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(target));
}
```

And my activity_main.xml layout (Yes....it's very ugly :) )

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.palarran.cycloops.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/storm_category"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/cyclone_shape"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clickable_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/storm_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorCycloneName"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="Fred"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/direction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorCycloneHeading"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="Heading 270 degrees W"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wind_speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorCycloneName"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="75"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorCycloneName"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="125 miles E"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/list_layout"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:name="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"
        class="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

LogCat says:

**ERROR**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.palarran.cycloops, PID: 25336
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.palarran.cycloops/com.palarran.cycloops.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0013 (com.palarran.cycloops:id/google_map) for fragment CycloneMap{95502b #0 id=0x7f0e0013}
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0013 (com.palarran.cycloops:id/google_map) for fragment CycloneMap{95502b #0 id=0x7f0e0013}
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:987)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
>                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:816)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
>                                                          at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6695)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Part of error that should be giving me the answer:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0013 (com.palarran.cycloops:id/google_map) for fragment CycloneMap{95502b #0 id=0x7f0e0013}

Sorry to dump this on everyone. Most of what I got, I got from [Android Dev Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

And so many StackOverFlow questions with the sorta same issue. But having no luck, so, I'm breaking down and asking for help.

As I understand it, I should be able to drop this or any Fragment into an Activity and run with it. Or am I misunderstanding?

My API keys and permissions in the Manifest are all good to go. And I have cleaned and rebuilt the project MANY, many times. But I'll include the Manifest in case i've missed something

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_cycloops"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MenuSettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings_title">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.palarran.cycloops.MenuSettingsActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CycloneMap"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC9d4qOHlPW4MnrEde3ucDOVrPzyvN1qBs"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

Thanks,
CB...

Comment: You posted code for `CycloneMapFragment extends Fragment` . Do you have another fragment named `CycloneMap` ? Then post that also.

Comment: SORRY....that was a refactor I did not catch....CycloneMap is the Fragment....there is no CycloneMapFragment....edited to corredt this....

Comment: `R.layout.cyclone_list` is the Activity layout, right? And `R.layout.activity_main` is the fragment layout?

Comment: That is where I think I might be messing up as well. R.layout.activity_main is the main Activity layout. R.layout.cyclone_list is a layout to hold my list that is created from the JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that in `R.layout.cyclon_list`, there is a container with id `google_map` . Now, inside the `CycloneMap` fragment, you are setting `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);`.

But looking into the layout activity_main,

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/list_layout"
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout">

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:name="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"
    class="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

You are reffering the same fragment class inside the fragment. Why is it so? declaring `class="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"` will recreate the whole fragment again inside the inner fragment. And this will continue as a loop.
If you need an inner fragment, use another class with another layout. Or you can give the container only inside the layout and add the fragment later through the code as you did inside the activity.

```
CycloneMap mapFrag = new CycloneMap();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, mapFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Ahh, Ok. The lights are slowly coming on. I misunderstood the documentation. I thought when I added the container <FrameLayout> I had to place the <Fragment> inside the container in the XML layout. Your answer helped me realize my mistake. The Fragment is still not fully loading, but I'm not getting that original error any longer. I need a little more code in my CycloneMap.java Fragment and the fragment should be up and working. Will update my question with what i've done per your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<activity android:name=".CycloneMap"/> // according to the code you have posted, CycloneMap is a fragment, so please remove this line
```

Secondly, while replacing or adding fragments, you need to pass the id of the container containing the fragment (in your case, it is the id of FrameLayout) as follows :

```
    CycloneMap mapFrag = new CycloneMap();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, mapFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, mapFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And last but not the least, please make sure that you have set the correct layout for the corresponding activity. For example, you have set cyclone_list in MainActivity as the content view. However, I don't see any such layout mentioned in your code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.cyclone_list); // it should be activity_main
```

Comment: Manifest was changed. That should have been commented out. I also tried to use R.id.fragment_layout before but get the same error. I believe the issue lies in your third suggestion. Changing setContentView to R.layout.acivity_main breaks the rest of the app. Posting link to branch on Github to main question above.

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to Nizam.

Changes made to correct errors:

**CODE** From activity_main.xml I removed

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/list_layout"
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout">

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:name="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"
    class="com.palarran.cycloops.CycloneMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Then added the following to cyclone_list.xml

**CODE**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/google_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

In MainActivity.java I changed

```
CycloneMap mapFrag = new CycloneMap();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.google_map, mapFrag);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.google_map, mapFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

to

```
CycloneMap mapFrag = new CycloneMap();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.google_map, mapFrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And finally in CycloneMap.java Fragment I changed

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```

}

to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.cyclone_list, container, false);
}
```

The fragment is still not loading...but I believe I am on the right track and the question about the error is answered and solved. I will continue to work on getting the Google Maps fragment to work. It is now at least trying to load in the correct place.

Thanks.